# Column known to GROUP BY, but unknown to HAVING

Tags: mysql

I have a very big query that in essence is like this:

```
SELECT a FROM
(SELECT a,b,c,d FROM table_name) AS tt
GROUP BY tt.b, tt.c, tt.d
HAVING SUM(tt.b)>0
```

The weird thing is that I get the error:

```
"Unknown column "b" in 'having clause'
```

When I remove the `HAVING` clause it works well despite having `"b"` in `GROUP BY`. So `b` is known to `GROUP BY`, but not to `HAVING`.

Also if I replace `"SELECT a FROM"` with `"SELECT * FROM"` in the first line, the error goes away, which again is wierd because MySQL does not need the columns used in `HAVING` to be selected.

Do you have any idea why I get this error?

Comment: I believe the aggregate in the having also needs to be in the SELECT

Comment: No, only in standard SQL that is necessary but not in MySQL.

Comment: Remove `tt.b` from `GROUP BY` clause and try again.

Comment: Plainly, your proposition is false! http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b124c3/1

Comment: @Strawberry, you're right but only for this example. My real query is so complicated and involves like 10 tables, but the outcome of the subquery is: http://i.imgur.com/oY9PJ2W.png
in which filtertype is the column for which i get the error. This is a phpmyadmin output and I don't know why the border for that variable is orange. maybe it has something to do with why i get that error.

Comment: Unfortunately, we can only go on the information provided.